# Pythagorean Quadruples Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

What are all the solutions to

$$2^{2x}+2^{2y}+1=n^2 $$

I tried using the parametrization of Pythagorean Quadruples, but it did not work quite well.

There are $2$ parametrizations:

$(2np,2mp,p^2-n^2-m^2,p^2+n^2+m^2)$

Or $(mp+nq,np-mq,p^2+q^2-n^2-m^2,p^2+q^2+n^2+m^2)$

The problem is that the first one doesn't generate all solutions, but worked in my proof.So...any help?

EDIT:What we want to show is that the only solutions are

${(2^{2y-1}+1)}^2=4^{2y-1}+4^y+1$

Comment: Do all the solutions have to be integers?

Comment: Why Pythagorean Triples? Is it a hint to this question?

Comment: One solution would be $x=y=1$ $n=3$.

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant Pythagorean Quadruples

Comment: Source of the problem???

Comment: Well, it is a modified cersion of a random problem my teacher gave to me.The original one is quite stupid, it doesnt ask about all the sols, but the biggest solution less than 2015.The proof provided was faulty too :D

Comment: you missed some factors of 2 in Lebesgue's four variable parametrization http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple#Parametrization_of_primitive_quadruples

Answer (score 1):

We must have
$$ 4^x + 4^y = (n-1)(n+1) \tag{1}$$
and $\gcd(n-1,n+1)\leq 2$, so by assuming $x\geq y$ and rewriting $(1)$ as
$$ 4^y\cdot\left(4^{x-y}+1\right) = (n-1)(n+1) \tag{2}$$
there are just a few cases to check.

Comment: Tried that, but didnt go so well.Could you elaborate how you manipulated the cases?

Comment: By the way, you are on brilliant, arent you?

Comment: If $n$ is even, we must have $y=0$ and $4^x+2=n^2$, no hope. If $x-y\geq 1$ and $n$ is odd, we must have $(n\pm 1)=2(4^{x-y}+1)$ and $(n\mp 1)=2^{2y-1}$. If $x-y=0$, we must have $2\cdot 4^x+1 = n^2$, so $x=1$ and $n=3$.

Comment: But why cant, for instance, n+1=2.a and n-1=2^{2y-1}b, where a.b=4^{x-y}+1?

Comment: @user211570: oh, ok, that may happen.